# ACC train is high from the first epoch but acc validation fluctuate a lot

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am using a data set from kaggle for binary image classification:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/danielbacioiu/tig-aluminium-5083

This is a data set for welding. In this data set 46 unique experiments were done for training data and 14 for test data. Each experiment is a unique folder with a lable good/bad and contains some images. So, each experiment differs from another one. In total I have 26,666 data points for training data. I used 10% of the training data as a validation data. However, training acc is high from the first epoch near 95% and test acc after 10 epochs is 91% buh validation acc fluctuate a lot. Why this happens? Why train acc is high from the beginning and validation acc fluctuate a lot?

Here is my code:

```
df["fault"] = df["fault"].astype(str)
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split=0.1)
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
directory="al5083/train",
x_col="image",
y_col="fault",
subset="training",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="binary",
target_size=(512,512))



valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
directory="al5083/train",
x_col="image",
y_col="fault",
subset="validation",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="binary",
target_size=(512,512))


#loading test data
with open('al5083/test/test.json', 'r') as f:
  datatest= json.load(f)

newdatatest=pd.DataFrame(datatest.items(), columns=['imagename', 'fault']) 

for i in range(len(newdatatest['fault'])):
    if newdatatest.loc[i,'fault']!=0:
       newdatatest.loc[i,'fault']=1

print(newdatatest)

newdatatest["fault"] = newdatatest ["fault"].astype(str)
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
test_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=newdatatest,
directory="al5083/test",
x_col="imagename",
y_col="fault",
#subset="training",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=False,
class_mode="binary",
target_size=(512,512),
batch_sizs=len(newdatatest))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16,(5,5),activation="relu",padding='same', input_shape=(512,512,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

#conv2
model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5),activation="relu",padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


#conv3
model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),activation="relu",padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
#conv4
model.add(Conv2D(128,(5,5),activation="relu",padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())


model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)

model.compile(optimizer='adam' , loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


faults=[1,2] 
fault=[1,2]
STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size



start = time.time()
history=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID, epochs=10)
```